# Discriminatively replacing one column's data with other columns in MySQL

Tags: replace, merge, sql-update

Given the table:

```
ID || City_1    || City_2
=====================
1  || Beijing   || null
2  || Stockholm || Paris
3  || Tokyo     || Seoul
4  || Las Vegas || null
5  || Moscow    || null
```

I would like to discriminatively put all non-nulls in column 2 to replace corresponding values in column 1 so that the new column 1 will look like this:

```
ID || City_1    || City_2
=====================
1  || Beijing   || null
2  || Paris     || Paris
3  || Seoul     || Seoul
4  || Las Vegas || null
5  || Moscow    || null
```

What would be the best syntax for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best syntax, but I will use

```
UPDATE table SET City_1=City_2 WHERE City_2 IS NOT NULL
```